# How to perform an action on double click for GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a [GridControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridGridControltopic).

```
    private void gridControl1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridControl grid = sender as GridControl;            
        DXMouseEventArgs args = e as DXMouseEventArgs;
        BaseHitInfo hitInfo = grid.Views[0].CalcHitInfo(args.Location);
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }
```

How can I display `MessageBox.Show("Hello World")` only if the user double clicks on **row data**?  The code above shows hello world even if the user double clicks on whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast `hitInfo` to `GridHitInfo` and check the `HitTest` property.